# encrypt decrypt using java, string to bit then some operation and back to string

Tags: java, string, encryption, binary, xor

I used these two methods for encryption and decryption (feistel) but they doesn't work probably 
they always give me the same output. Any one have any idea how to fix them please?

here is the encrypt mesthod, takes a string then convert it to bit and then split it, then do some operation on part2 after splitting it then xor it with part1, then swap and make xor the second part and part2 the first. for 2 rounds.

```
  public static String encrypt(String s) {

String str = s;

for(int i = 0 ; i<=1 ; i++) {

// split-convert for function + xor 
String part1 = str.substring(0, str.length() / 2);
String part2 = str.substring(str.length() / 2);
byte[] part1Bytes = part1.getBytes();
byte[] part2Bytes = part2.getBytes();
BitSet part1BitSet = BitSet.valueOf(part1Bytes);
BitSet part2BitSet = BitSet.valueOf(part2Bytes);
BitSet temp = part2BitSet;

// key based on i 
if (i == 0) 
part2BitSet.or(new BitSet(7)); // key 7 

if (i == 1)
part2BitSet.or(new BitSet(11)); // key 11

// xor
part2BitSet.xor(part1BitSet);

// swap
byte[] split1 = part2BitSet.toByteArray(); 
byte[] split2 = temp.toByteArray();
String sS1 = split1.toString();
String sS2 = split2.toString();

str = sS1+""+sS2;
}

// convert to String
String AfterEnc = ""; // need to convert

return str;
}
```

method decrypt do the opposite and must give the exact string before encryption.

```
public static String decrypt(String s) {

String str = s;

for(int i = 0 ; i<=1 ; i++) {

String part1 = str.substring(0, str.length() / 2);
String part2 = str.substring(str.length() / 2);
byte[] part1Bytes = part1.getBytes();
byte[] part2Bytes = part2.getBytes();
BitSet part1BitSet = BitSet.valueOf(part1Bytes);
BitSet part2BitSet = BitSet.valueOf(part2Bytes);
BitSet temp = part1BitSet;

// key based on i 
if (i == 0) 
part1BitSet.or(new BitSet(11)); // key 7 

if (i == 1)
part1BitSet.or(new BitSet(7)); // key 11

// xor
part1BitSet.xor(part2BitSet);

// swap
byte[] split1 = part1BitSet.toByteArray(); 
byte[] split2 = temp.toByteArray();
String sS1 = split1.toString();
String sS2 = split2.toString();

str = sS2+""+sS1;

}

return str;

}
```

thank you.

Comment: Running `toString()` on an array doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: sS1 = new String(split1); String sS1; The same for sS2.

Comment: Then which method does what I think it must do?